# Get the href innertext with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-agility-pack, html-parser

I am trying to create a news agent to get the news from the websites.so i have to use a `html parser` like `HtmlAgilityPack` .so here you ca see my code :

```
public async void parsing(string website)
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    var response = await http.GetByteArrayAsync(website);
    String source = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetString(response, 0, response.Length - 1);
    source = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(source);
    HtmlDocument resultat = new HtmlDocument();
    resultat.LoadHtml(source);
    List<HtmlNode> toftitle = resultat.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where
      (x => (x.Name == "div" && x.Attributes["class"] != null && x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("latest-news"))).ToList();
    var li = toftitle[0].Descendants("li").ToList();
    foreach (var item in li)
    {
        var link = item.Descendants("a").ToList()[0].GetAttributeValue("href", null);
        var img = item.Descendants("img").ToList()[0].GetAttributeValue("src", null);
    }
}
```

here is my html code that should be parsed :

```
<a href="/news?p_p_id=56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh&amp;_56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh_mode=news&amp;_56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh_newsId=3153832&amp;p_p_state=maximized">› پانل «بررسي سازوکارهاي تأمين منابع مالي براي توسعۀ فناوري» به‌عنوان پانل برتر پنجمين کنفرانس بين‌المللي و نهمين کنفرانس ملي مديريت فناوري معرفي شد</a>


<a href="/news?p_p_id=56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh&amp;_56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh_mode=news&amp;_56_INSTANCE_tVzMoLp4zfGh_newsId=3135970&amp;p_p_state=maximized">› فرآیند و فرم درخواست استفاده از تسهیلات حمایتی بلاعوض صندوق نوآوری و شکوفایی جهت حضور شرکت های دانش بنیان در جایزه ملی مدیریت فناوری و نوآوری</a>
```

So the problem is i can get the `href link` but not `href value` .I mean i can get the news url but not title `پانل «بررسي سازوکارهاي تأمين منابع مالي براي توسعۀ فناوري» به‌عنوان پانل برتر پنجمين کنفرانس بين‌المللي و نهمين کنفرانس ملي مديريت فناوري معرفي شد`.

How can i get that ?

Comment: There is only one value for href, the link. The "title" you want is the innertext of the a element.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen so how can i get that innertext?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i edit the post,i just added one of the li elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just should use this code to get the innertext of href :

```
string tistle = item.Descendants("a").ToList()[0].InnerText;
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use like this :

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(result);
 foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("a"))
        {
            string value = link.InnerText; // here you can get href value 
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be cleaned up a bit to something like this :

```
List<HtmlNode> toftitle = resultat.DocumentNode
                                  .Descendants("div")
                                  .Where(x => GetAttributeValue("class","").Contains("latest-news"))
                                  .First();
foreach (HtmlNode item in toftitle.Descendants("li"))
{
    var link = item.Descendants("a").First();
    var url = link.GetAttributeValue("href", null); //get the link url
    var text = link.InnerText.Trim(); //get the link text

    var img = item.Descendants("img").First().GetAttributeValue("src", null);
}
```

Basically, you're supposed to use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `ToList()[0]` to get the first item of `IEnumerable<T>`.